# Preview won't open gif created with imagemagick

Tags: preview

Preview won't open a gif I made with imagemagick. The full error message is:

```
The file “insta.gif” could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

However, Firefox opens and plays the gif no problem. The gif is about 7 MB.

Comment: Does Safari open the file?

Comment: So it's an animated GIF not a plain GIF?

Comment: If the gif opens normally in Firefox but not with Preview, try to coalesce the image frames in Imagemagick.

Comment: Been a while but coalesce worked, though I had to tinker with resizing the gif after coalescing.